# Konica Minolta Printer MIBs?

Tags: monitoring, network-printer

I'm looking for a MIB for a Konica Minolta BizHub 600. The product's [support page](http://onyxftp.mykonicaminolta.com/download/SearchResults.aspx?productid=876) doesn't appear to have the MIBs in any section. Various combinations of search terms produce mostly marketing pages and a few people asking for KM MIBs. MibSearch, MibDepot, and ByteSphere all come up empty.

KM does offer an application, PageScope Net Care, which, on first glance, looks like KM's solution for monitoring. However, I already have a monitoring setup I'm happy with, and I'm not looking to set up something new (especially for this one, relatively noncritical machine).

Where else can I look for this information?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use `snmpwalk` to try to find it.

http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/man/snmpwalk.html